# Feeding a spark dataset as a java reader in csv format

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement my own `org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer` and I need to pass the contents of my `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` in csv format to my Java library which accepts a `java.io.reader`. I am struggling here because it seems this is really two different worlds. Ideally I don't want to have to create a string out of it, I would want to stream it. At this specific step the data shouldn't be larger than about a gigabyte though so I guess I could make do with a String solution if it is absolutely needed.

In an attempt to get a string I tried something like:

```
  class Bla (override val uid: String) extends Transformer {

  [...]  

  def transform(df: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString(","))
  [...]
```

But I get several errors:

- value mkString is not a member of _$1
- polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type; found :
  [U]org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U] 
  required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame (which expands to)
  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

So any suggestions?

---

Edit: I have made a little outline of what I need to at https://github.com/jonalv/spark_java_problem

Comment: Spark transformers only apply when you are working in the Dataframe context. Don´t execute the action .rdd inside a transformer. I think that you would be able to achieve that with a mappartition o foreachpartition after a rdd transformation.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 I don't quite understand you. First you say "Don´t execute the action .rdd inside a transformer" then you say "I think that you would be able to achieve that with a mappartition o foreachpartition after a rdd transformation" which I thought was exactly what you told me not to do, that rdd transformation that is...

Comment: I meant that you use a foreachpartitions with the RDD but don´t use transformers. Within a foreachpartition you will have an iterator for each partition and you will be able to call your java function inside that block.

Comment: But what I want to do is wrap this java library inside transformers/predictors so that it can be used as a part of the ML pipeline framework.

Comment: This can be a little bit tricky... In that case create an udf tat receives each row and you can call the function and still using the transformer. There is no need to convert your DF to a RDD

Comment: So I will call that function for each row in `df`? But what to you mean that function should do? Do you mean that function should create the stream and send it to my Java code and then I will use that function inside the transform?

Comment: that indeed works in that way. A transformer operates over each row so you should create a stream for each row. Something not very efficient but it would work. Transformer´s api are not designed to contain state if you attempt to do something like that, the transformer´s behavior could be unpredictable. Keep in mind that all the Spark ML pipelines only offer an api for data transformation, model optimization and prediction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213634/discussion-between-jonalv-and-emicareofcell44).